# How to add images and multiple links in Leaflet's Markers/Popups?

Tags: html, arrays, json, leaflet

I wish to add images and multiple links in a **leaflet popup**, what should I do and how?

I have already tried by changing .json code array to add multiple links  but that does not help me, it just displays the second array variable's link without showing the previous one.

```
markers = [
   {
     "name": "Canada",
     "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada",
     "lat": 56.130366,
     "lng": -106.346771
   },
   {
   "name": "Canada",
   "url":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anguilla",
   "lat": 56.130369,
     "lng": -106.346779
   }
}
```

i expect for the popup to show different different links beneath the popup name.

Answer (score 1):

You could make an array such as:

```
 { "name": "Canada", "url": ["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USA"], "lat": 56.130366, "lng": -106.346771 }
```

and in the popup template just cycle the array with a forEach making a list element for every element in markers.url.